NLog not writing to ApplicationInsightsTarget in ASP.NET Core
I'm noticing this behavior in an Asp.NET Core 8.0 application.  This is some new behavior that is not present in .NET Framework 4.8
These are the relevant NuGet packages that I'm using:

I'm using the nlog.development.config configuration file below.
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="Seq.Client.NLog" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="seq" xsi:type="Seq" serverUrl="http://localhost:5341" />
    <target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="seq" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="aiTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>

I setup logging in the Main method using the code below:
            var appInsightsConnectionString = builder.Configuration["AppInsightsConnectionString"];
            var appInsightsOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
            {
                EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
                ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString
            };
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(appInsightsOptions);

            var nlogConfigFile = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment() ? "nlog.development.config" : "nlog.config";
            LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration(nlogConfigFile);
            builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => { loggingBuilder.AddNLog(); });

The ILogger<ScheduleController> logger instance that is injected into the ScheduleController class has both "seq" and aiTarget" targets - it writes to both locations.  Yet a _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("TraceLogger"); call later on in the code returns an instance that no longer writes into the "aiTarget", only into the "seq".  How should I go about fixing this behavior please, yet maintain backwards compatibility with .NET Framework 4.8?
I'm also wondering why is it that the builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => { loggingBuilder.AddNLog(); }); call in a Dev environment loads the nlog.config file instead of the nlog.development.config.

Make sure your nlog.development.config contains explicit logger rules for both ILogger and LogManager.GetLogger. Add specific rules if necessary to ensure both logger instances write to the intended targets.. Double-check that builder.Environment.IsDevelopment() correctly identifies your development environment. Verify the existence and path of nlog.development.config to ensure it’s loaded instead of nlog.config.

Maintain compatibility with .NET Framework 4.8 by using library versions that support both platforms and avoid using platform-specific features without conditional checks.

Maybe you need to set EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup:
            var appInsightsOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
            {
                EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
                ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString,
                EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true,
            };
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(appInsightsOptions);

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2070
When troubleshooting logging in NLog, then it is also a good idea to look at output from NLog Internal-logging.

Thanks very much for all your help!
I made sure that the App Insights and NLog related dependencies are identical with the .NET Framework 4.8 projects, but that did not solve the problem.
Setting EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true did solve the problem.
